# Create Generic function for findOneAndUpdate Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to create a Generic Function For findOneAndUpdate Query.
So My Function is Like

```
var findAndUpdate = function(req, res, activityname, CollectionName){
    CollectionName.findOneAndUpdate({activityname: req.body.user_id},  function(err, data){
        if(err){
            res.send('error');
        } else {
           res.send('data')
        }
    });
};
```

And calling a function like this

```
findAndUpdate(req, res, 'user_id', User);
```

But here is the only problem is on activityname. If I pass directly 'user_id' under Query then it returns data otherwise nothing return. Like this

```
var findAndUpdate = function(req, res, activityname, CollectionName){
    CollectionName.findOneAndUpdate({'user_id': req.body.user_id},  function(err, data){
        if(err){
            res.send('error');
        } else {
           res.send('data')
        }
    });
};
```

I also tried to provide 'user_id' exactly like this after getting the value from variable. Like this but still not getting

```
var findAndUpdate = function(req, res, activityname, CollectionName){
var uid = ("'"+activityname+"'");
    CollectionName.findOneAndUpdate({uid : req.body.user_id},  function(err, data){
        if(err){
            res.send('error');
        } else {
           res.send('data')
        }
    });
};
```

Anyone Knows how it can be solved.??

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is simple javascript and not depending of MongoDB. For example, writing

```
var toto = {age: 12};
```

or

```
var toto = {'age': 12};
```

will have exactly the same effect. If you want to dynamically define a property name, you can do it like this :

```
var prop = 'age';
var toto = {};
toto[prop] = 12;
```

In your case, you can achieve what you want this way:

```
var findAndUpdate = function(req, res, activityname, CollectionName){
  var filter = {};
  filter[activityname] = req.body.user_id;
  CollectionName.findOneAndUpdate(filter,  function(err, data){
    if(err){
        res.send('error');
    } else {
       res.send('data')
    }
  });
};
```